# Can I take actions in didReceiveRemoteNotification: while app is in the background/suspended?

Tags: ios, background, apple-push-notifications

Will the app "wake up for a while", or something?

I have to send some data to a remote server when a notification is arrived (not when the app opened).

Is it possible to implement this with Push Notifications?

Comment: I think you cant do action in didReceiveRemoteNotification: methd. because the action will work only when you open the app

Comment: Ya, I was afraid of, but I wanted to know it for sure.

Comment: I have to maintain a connection with some kind of setKeepAliveTimeout then...

Answer (score 1):

by implementing push notifications, if your app is in background and a notification is received than the user would be alerted with ok or view later message, if user presses Ok than your app would be launched and you can do whatever you want, else you can check for pending notification on next launch!!

Answer (score 0):

This delegate is not called when the app is in backgroud or suspended, but it's called when the app is waking up from backgroud or when it's launched after opening a push notification.